# What ADO type is the Geography spatial type from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, spatial-query

I am looking to refactor this method (from [Massive.cs by Rob Conery](https://github.com/robconery/massive/blob/master/Massive.cs)):

```
public static void AddParam(this DbCommand cmd, object item) {
    var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = string.Format("@{0}", cmd.Parameters.Count);
    if (item == null) {
        p.Value = DBNull.Value;
    } else {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(Guid)) {
            p.Value = item.ToString();
            p.DbType = DbType.String;
            p.Size = 4000;
        } else if (item.GetType() == typeof(ExpandoObject)) {
            var d = (IDictionary<string, object>)item;
            p.Value = d.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        } else {
            p.Value = item;
        }
        //from DataChomp
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(string))
            p.Size = 4000;
    }
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
}
```

Likely adding a check for Geography type will fix my issue with ExecuteNonQuery and spatial data types, but what type would I check for?

`if (item.GetType() == typeof(//WhatType?//)) {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SqlGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) is what you're looking for, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, once I get back to my workstation, I'll check this... seems like a great candidate though. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
if (item.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography)) 
{
     SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
     p.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt;
     p.UdtTypeName = "geography";
     p.Value = value;
}
```